# Downloading multimedia files of a directory into my local machine using java code

Tags: java, file-io, ftp

I have a java code which i would be using to download the files from a directory in a remote machine.Now is use the ftp class available to do the same.The problem arises when i run the code which results in all the files being downloaded but when i see the size of all of them i see that all are of zero bytes and do not contain anything either.Kindly help if you can to analyze what could be the possible reason behind this?

```
package login.multiple;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.*; 
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

public class Downloader {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FTPException 
     * @throws FTPIllegalReplyException 
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws IllegalStateException 
     * @throws FTPListParseException 
     * @throws FTPAbortedException 
     * @throws FTPDataTransferException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FTPFile[] list = null;
        String fileNames[];
        String path = "\\Users\\XXX\\Documents\\Downloads\\Coldplay - Mylo Xyloto [mp3-vbr-2011]";
        int i = 0;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        //client.connect("192.168.1.2");
        try {
            client.connect("127.0.0.1");
            client.login("xxx", "yyy");
            list = client.listFiles(path);
            for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
            //for(i=0;i<1;i++){
                fos = new FileOutputStream(list[i].getName());
                client.retrieveFile(path + list[i].getName(), fos);
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are opening the `FileOutputStream`, a good chance is that you are responsible for closing it, too. Add `fos.close()` after `client.retrieveFile`. Your try-catch design is a mess, too. It will help the diagnostics if you get it right. Put everything **after** `client.connect` into a `try {...} finally { client.disconnect(); }` and declare your `main` method as `throws Exception`. That will give you a fail-fast behaviour.

Comment: i tried doing that too @Marko Topolnik.Could it be some problem with the permissions?

Comment: *"a good chance is that you are responsible for closing it, too."*  [`FTPClient.retrieveFile(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)  goes further. *"Retrieves a named file from the server and writes it to the given OutputStream. This method does NOT close the given OutputStream."*  (their caps, not mine).  ;)  +1

Comment: Exactly, so you definitely need to put that `close` in there, even if that is not your *only* problem.

Comment: String path = "\\Users\\XXX\\Documents\\Downloads\\Coldplay - Mylo Xyloto [mp3-vbr-2011]";

Comment: So if the file in that directory was file.txt it was appended since i was doing path + filename. It was coming in the format "\\Users\\XXX\\Documents\\Downloads\\Coldplay - Mylo Xyloto [mp3-vbr-2011]file.txt" instead of "\\Users\\XXX\\Documents\\Downloads\\Coldplay - Mylo Xyloto [mp3-vbr-2011]\\file.txt".Thus the difference...